# Where does windows cls.exe reside?

Tags: windows, cmd

As we know windows CMD can clear the scren by `cls.exe` command. But I cannot find the command location.

Usually, I can use `which` to find the location of the command program file.
But for `cls.exe`, it does not work, and displays as:

```
which: no cls in c:\Windows\System32...
```

Could you guys help me how cmd works? I searched on the internet, only finding clues on how to use it. Not how itself works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built-in command to `cmd.exe` and not a stand-alone program.

i.e. `cls.exe` does not exist:

```
C:\>"cls.exe"
'"cls.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>"cls.com"
'"cls.com"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>"find.exe"
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

The last one, `find.exe`, is just there to show what happens when it exists.

Answer (score 4):

There is no cls.exe.  'cls' is an CMD.EXE internal built-in.

Answer (score 0):

With the frrst Releases of IBM's PC-DOS, it WAS necessary to use CLS.EXE, an External Command, as it had not yet been included in PC-DOS v1 and v1.1 - Peter Norton, of 'Norton Utilities' fame, wrote the CLS.EXE Program, I believe in 1982-ish time frame